# make runs all targets

Tags: makefile

I want to write a makefile only for installing. I was thinking of having an `install` target and an `all` target. The `all` target would only exist as the default target so running `make` would say something like "Nothing to build". However, when I do a small test and run `make` or `make all`, it seems that the install target is also run. Here is the makefile:

```
vimprefix=/usr/share/vim/vim73

.PHONY: all
all: 
    @echo "Nothing to build. Run `make install` to install configurations."

.PHONY: install
install:
    test -d $(vimprefix)
```

And here is the output from `make`:

```
$ make
Nothing to build. Run make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/documents/conf'
test -d /usr/share/vim/vim73
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/documents/conf' to install configurations.
```

I noticed that this doesn't happen if I put something like `touch all` in the `all` target. Can someone explain why this might be happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heh, nice one. :)

```
Run `make install` to
```

This contains backticks, which invokes the command `make install`. Use simple apostrophes.

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahaha, oh my god I can't believe that's what was causing it. Thank you!! =D. It is so obvious now, too, because the echo stops right there and clearly invokes make again in the output. (sorry about not upvoting you, btw. I don't have the rep to do that yet T_T)